# Pass an array containing numbers as a parameter c++

Tags: c++, class

I have a class with a constructor that takes three arguments

```
class Foo{
public: Foo(int, double[], double[]);
};

Foo::Foo(int a, double b[], double c[]){
// function
}
```

Now what I'm trying is to call this class with arrays that have fixed numbers
for example

```
Foo(4, [4.1, 2.5, 7.2], [5.5, 6.1, 3.8]);
```

yet this doesn't work. Is such syntax possible in c++ or do I have to change it.

I tried doing it by declaring array variables before like

```
 double x[5];
 x[0] = 4.1;
 x[1] = 2.5;
 x[2] = 7.2;

 Foo(4, x, x);
```

this works but takes way to much time since I want to create multiple of these classes and this would make my code way bigger and unnecessary if there is a better way of doing it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Where did you learn that `[4.1, 2.5, 7,2]` is a C++ notation for an array? If you haven't and simply try to guess the C++ grammar, don't. Get [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) instead.

Comment: I am trying to get something that works as similar as this. Please read the entire question first.

Comment: A `double[]` parameter is actually a `double*` parameter.

Comment: You are allowed to initialise arrays, you don't need to assign them elementwise – `double x[5] = {4.1, 2.5, 7.2};`

Comment: Use `std::array` (or `std::vector`).

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using standard library containers:

```
class Foo{
   public:
     Foo(int, const std::vector<double>& vv ) : v(vv) 
     {
       // other stuff here
     }

     std::vector<double> v;
};
```

You can pass values this way, using [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

```
int main()
{
    Foo f( 1, {1.1,1.2,1.3} );
}
```

Or use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if compile-time fixed size.

Answer (score 2):

In such case [std::initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) is best choice.

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo(int n, std::initializer_list<double> a, std::initializer_list<double> b);
};

Foo foo { 32, {}, { 2, 3, 1, 2 }};
```

[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4z3jDatribVs5EcS).

Answer (score 1):

Declaring lists using `[]` will not work. But you can use [brace enclosed initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

```cpp
double b[] = {1.0, 2.0};
double c[] = {5.3, 4.7};
Foo f = Foo(1, b, c);
```

Note however, you cannot do this:

```cpp
Foo f = Foo(1, {1.0, 2.0}, {5.3, 4.7});
```

Why? Because initializer lists can't convert inline to arrays. You have to declare the arrays explicitly. If you want to do this inline, use a `std::vector<double>`.

Comment: *"Because initializer lists can't convert inline to arrays"* In `Foo(int a, double b[], double c[])`, `b` and `c` are actually pointers, not arrays. If you use const reference on array (as you can't pass array by value) the conversion happens: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc7efd1017346aa4).